# How to set opacity of a single bubble in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, bubble-chart

I want to set the opacity of a single bubble in HighCharts. 
I tried setting fillOpacity to the options of the data of the bubble.
I also tried to use RGBA on the fillColor of the data of the bubble. Like this:

```
 chart: {
        type: 'bubble',
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },

    series: [{
        marker: {
            fillColor: 'rgba(47,226,216,1)',
            fillOpacity: 0.8
        },
        data: [{
            x: 10,
            y: 90,
            z: 79,
            marker: {
                fillColor: 'rgba(47,226,216,0.5)',
                fillOpacity: 0.5
            }
        }, [90, 10, 60],
            [50, 50, 1]
        ]
    }]
```

See jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kzoon/2Gbja/

But that didn't change the opacity (changing the color of the first bubble DOES work, but not it's opacity)

Comment: it is working in your jsfiddle

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/shafeeq116/fLx2P/

Answer (score 3):

Try to set color, instead of fillColor, and set it for point: http://jsfiddle.net/2Gbja/1/

```
       data: [{
            x: 10,
            y: 90,
            z: 79,
            color: 'rgba(47,226,216,0.1)'

        }, [90, 10, 60],
            [50, 50, 1]
        ]
```

Comment: The alpha channel on the rgba value is critical here. I've found that if I just used a hex or rgb color, the chart would use it's default opacity of 0.75.